# Save Excel spreadsheet as .csv with R?

Tags: excel, r

What is the simplest way to convert a large Excel spreadsheet with multiple worksheets into .CSV files in R?

Note that I've tested XLConnect and XLSX and found that my Excel sheets cause it to crash. So I'm specifically looking for a solution that does not use the XLConnect or XLSX package.

Comment: Why not just use excel to convert into CSV?

Comment: @Stedy - Perhaps the Excel spreadsheet is generated as part of a automated periodic process that AME can't modify but still has to work with.  Alternatively, maybe AME actually has 5,000 such Excel sheets and needs to extract multiple sheets from each, but already knows how to loop across files.  I can think of a great many scenarios in which manual conversion becomes nightmarish.

Comment: Not to mention that, from a reproducible research standpoint, it is often better to treat the excel sheet as 'primary' (e.g. if it comes from a collaborator) and do the processing, including conversion, in R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:data-io:ms_windows

EDIT: to address the read.xlsx option:

If you have Perl running, you need a current version of gdata

```
require(gdata)
installXLSXsupport()   #now the example from help(read.xls)
    # load the third worksheet, skipping the first two non-data lines...
    if( 'XLSX' %in% xlsFormats() )  # if XLSX is supported..
      data <- read.xls(exampleFile2007, sheet="Sheet with initial text", skip=2)
 data
#-----------------------
   X       X.1 D E.  F  G Factor
1 NA  FirstRow 1 NA NA NA   Red 
2 NA SecondRow 2  1 NA NA Green 
3 NA  ThirdRow 3  2  1 NA   Red 
4 NA FourthRow 4  3  2  1 Black 
#------------------------
write.csv(data)
```

This was done on a Mac and up until this question I had always stumbled at the installXLSXsupport() stage since I always got an error. This time I started up Perl from a Terminal command line, and got success after first setting up my personal configuration, defining CPAN mirrors on my continent, and I left perl running.

Comment: That's a great resource, but I think your answer would be even better if you included some personal commentary on which options you've used and your experiences with them.  It's hard to know where to start on a list like that.

Comment: Even as you noted in your comment, it would have been difficult to render an answer tailored to the questioners situation because there were no details of such offered. It seemed a general response was called for to answer a vague question and hopefully elicit clarifying details.

Comment: Thanks for the link DWin. This question actually relates to an issue I had with the XLConnect and XLSX packages being unable to read a particularly large .xlsx file. If I manually convert the spreadsheets into a CSV file my R code works just fine. So, in order to automate the process, I need to use a R package that can read large .xlsx files and convert them into .csv files. After reading your reference, I think I'll give gdata a shot. Can you help me figure out how I convert .xlsx files using the "gdata" package?

Comment: @AME The comments are not the appropriate place for extended help and follow up questions. Try some more stuff and if you get stuck again ask a separate question.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a loop to write out all sheets:

```
require(gdata)
## install support for xlsx files
installXLSXsupport()
excelFile <- ("/full/path/to/excelFile.xlsx")
## note that the perl scripts that gdata uses do not cope well will tilde expansion
## on *nix machines. So use the full path. 
numSheets <- sheetCount(excelFile, verbose=TRUE)

for ( i in 1:numSheets) {
  mySheet <- read.xls(excelFile, sheet=i)
  write.csv(mySheet, file=paste(i, "csv", sep="."), row.names=FALSE)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer based on readxl package.

```
library("readxl")

#function to read all sheets of a workbook
read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename) {
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
  x <-    lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = X))
  names(x) <- sheets
  x
}

sheetnames <- read_excel_allsheets("excelFile.xlsx")
names(sheetnames)
```

Comment: Simple and recommended.  
`read_excel(file) %>% data.table::fwrite(fileout)`