# Oil Bulletin weekly fuel data: import to R

Tags: r, excel, vba

#### Background

European Commission gathers and publishes weekly average prices of motor fuels in Europe. However, they publish it in a way that is painfull to work with. By pressing this [link](http://ec.europa.eu/energy/observatory/reports/Oil_Bulletin_Prices_History.xls) one can download the data in .xls format and have a look at it.

I emailed the Commission asking if they could publish the data in a [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) like structure, but they answered that thay have no intention to do it.

#### Question

Has anybody managed to programmaticaly either import this kind of data into R or tidy it in VBA prior to importing it to R, for say, first tab: "Prices wo taxes, per CTR"?

#### What I tried

I usually manually stack country tables one under the other in Excel and do some other transformations and save tidier data as say .csv and than import it into R.

Thank you in advance.

#### Edit

Please note that data is provided per country.

Comment: Which of the tabs do you need? There's different data on each tab.. Here's how I would start: use the readxl package. Read the Tabnames and filter the tabs you don't need. E.g. get rid of the charts. Then basically do sg. similar to this here: list_sheets <- excel_sheets(filepath)
  list_tables <- lapply(list_sheets, read_excel, path = filepath, col_names = col_names)
  list_tables <- rbindlist(list_tables)

Comment: like I wrote...say "Prices wo taxes, per CTR"

Comment: Sorry just realized that there's data beneath the first set. Should have read it more thouroughly.

Answer (score 1):

```
url = "http://ec.europa.eu/energy/observatory/reports/Oil_Bulletin_Prices_History.xls"
download.file(url=url, "data/PriceHistory.xls")

require(XLConnect)
wb <- XLConnect::loadWorkbook("data/PriceHistory.xls")
dt <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet = 1, startRow = 1, endRow = 14992)
dt.body <- dt[7:14992, 2:7]
dt.head <- c("Date", "ExcRate", "EuroSuper", "GasOilAuto", "GasOilHeat", "FuelOil")
colnames(dt.body) <- dt.head

dt.body <- dt.body[nchar(dt.body$Date) == nchar(dt.body$Date[1]), ]
dt.body[["Date"]] <- as.Date(dt.body[["Date"]], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

for(i in 2:ncol(dt.body)) {
    dt.body[, i] <- as.numeric(dt.body[, i])
}
```

Remove the rows with `NA` if you like but think about `ExcRate` column

```
# dt.body <- na.omit(dt.body)
rownames(dt.body) <- NULL
dt.body <- dplyr::tbl_dt(dt.body)

dt.body
```

The result is (After `na.omit`),

```
Source: local data table [11,054 x 6]

         Date ExcRate EuroSuper GasOilAuto GasOilHeat FuelOil
       (date)   (dbl)     (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)   (dbl)
1  2016-03-07       1    371.64     387.86     358.08     176
2  2016-02-29       1    370.81     382.03     344.54     171
3  2016-02-22       1    375.81     384.53     339.44     171
4  2016-02-15       1    369.97     372.03     331.05     171
5  2016-02-08       1    382.47     380.36     337.09     178
6  2016-02-01       1    387.47     376.19     337.01     172
7  2016-01-25       1    384.97     370.36     321.67     146
8  2016-01-18       1    392.47     385.36     329.30     165
9  2016-01-11       1    413.31     407.86     346.26     175
10 2016-01-04       1    418.31     412.86     363.64     176
..        ...     ...       ...        ...        ...     ...
```

#### Session Info:

```
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.3 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] MASS_7.3-45      ggplot2_2.0.0    dplyr_0.4.3      data.table_1.9.7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.3      digest_0.6.9     assertthat_0.1   chron_2.3-47    
 [5] grid_3.2.4       R6_2.1.2         plyr_1.8.3       gtable_0.1.2    
 [9] DBI_0.3.1        magrittr_1.5     scales_0.3.0     pls_2.5-0       
[13] labeling_0.3     tools_3.2.4      munsell_0.4.3    parallel_3.2.4  
[17] colorspace_1.2-6
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the effort. It does not work on my machine yet...I get some errors. Could you paste also your `sessionInfo()`? And also, the table lacks country codes.

Comment: I have added the sessionInfo in the answer, but what is the error you are getting??

Comment: I am on Windows OS machine and using your solution gives the following error: `Error: IOException (Java): Your file contains 20919 sectors, but the initial DIFAT array at index 20 referenced block # 658688. This isn't allowed and  your file is corrupt` I do not know, it seems to be some Java related issue.

Comment: I am not sure what is the error,  it may be the problem with `XLConnect`, you can use `gdata` or other package to get the excel file into R.

Comment: Apart from the error I get, there is stil one more thing. Your solution lacks the country codes, since the data is published by country. I will upvote your answer anyway, but for now it is a partial solution.

Comment: Sorry for that, you did not talked anything about country code. Anyway I will try if I get some time today.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TheRimalaya's code (change the download destination if necessary)

and then add this to make the imported data tidy:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dt.body.tidy <- dt.body %>%
        gather(fueltype, price, 3:ncol(dt.body), -ExcRate)

dt.body.tidy <- dt.body.tidy %>%
        filter(ExcRate == 1)

library(ggplot2)
dt.body.tidy %>%
        ggplot(aes(Date, price)) +
        geom_line(color="darkgrey") +
        geom_line(stat="summary", fun.y="median", color="red", size=0.3)+
        facet_wrap(~fueltype, ncol=1)
```

Addmittedly, this imports only the first worksheet, and has the values for startrow and endrow hardcoded, but you can adapt the code to your needs.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort, however on my Windows machine the code provided by TheRimalaya does not work (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Answers posted before my own are partial solutions. I decided to post mine that was somewhat influenced by them.

#### Download file

```
url = "http://ec.europa.eu/energy/observatory/reports/Oil_Bulletin_Prices_History.xls"
download.file(url = url, "PriceHistory.xls")
```

#### Assumptions

Following the 
[Save Excel spreadsheet as .csv with R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188415/save-excel-spreadsheet-as-csv-with-r) one can open Excel file and save the tabs as separate .csv files delimited by say `\t`. Assuming one saves three of them in working directory (**"Prices wo taxes, per CTR"**, **"Prices with taxes, per CTR"**, **"All taxes, per CTR"**) and names them like `mpc_ex_taxes.txt`, `mpc.txt`, `taxes.txt`, the code below should work.

#### Libraries used

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
```

#### Getting data from .csv files

```
# name of .txt files
my_file_name <- 
  c("mpc_ex_taxes", "mpc", "taxes")
  # c("mpc")

my_files <- 
  str_c(my_file_name, ".txt")

# getting data at once
my_file_list <- list()

for(file in seq_along(my_files)){

# read data: line by line (assuming you are in working directory)
  # my_oil <- read_lines(my_files[1])
  my_oil <- read_lines(my_files[file])

# split by delimiter
my_oil_split <- str_split(my_oil, "\t")

# compute length of vector in each line
my_len <- sapply(my_oil_split, length)

# filter lines with vector length equal to 9
my_data <-
  my_oil_split[which(my_len == 9)] %>% 
  ldply(.) %>% 
  tbl_df

# offset rows by this integer (used below in selecting data values)
my_number_to_add <- 4

# get country codes; str_length(V1) == 2
# get index_of_data; my_number_to_add lower than country code
my_geos <-
  my_data %>% 
  select(V1) %>%
  add_rownames(., var = "index_geo") %>% 
  filter(str_length(V1) == 2) %>% 
  mutate(index_geo = as.numeric(index_geo),
         index_of_data = index_geo + my_number_to_add) %>% 
  rename(geo = V1)

# calculate index where data for each country starts and where data ends
my_data_values <- 
  my_data %>% 
  add_rownames(., var = "index_of_data") %>% 
  filter(str_length(V2) == 8) %>% 
  mutate(index_of_data = as.integer(index_of_data),
         diff_index_of_data = index_of_data - lag(index_of_data, 1),
         index_of_data_end = index_of_data - diff_index_of_data) %>% 
  filter(is.na(diff_index_of_data) | diff_index_of_data > 1) %>% 
  mutate(index_of_data_end = lead(index_of_data_end, 1)) %>% 
  select(matches("^index"))

# join country codes and start and end of data values
my_case <- 
  left_join(my_geos, my_data_values) %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(.))

# get data for each country except the last one (UK)
my_data_list <- list()

for(i in seq_along(my_case$geo)){
  my_data_list[[i]] <- 
    my_data[my_case$index_of_data[i]:my_case$index_of_data_end[i], ]
}

names(my_data_list) <- my_case$geo

# tidy dataset
my_df <-
  ldply(my_data_list) %>% 
  tbl_df %>% 
  rename(geo = .id) %>%
  select(geo, V2:V7) %>% 
  mutate(my_date = as.Date(dmy(V2))) %>% 
  select(-V2) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(str_replace_all(., ",", ""))) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(as.numeric), matches("V")) %>% 
  select(geo, my_date, everything())

# renaming the variables
my_names <-  c("my_geo", "my_date", "ExcRate", "Gasoline", 
               "Diesel", "GasOilHeat", "FuelOil")

names(my_df) <- my_names

my_df_to_save <-
  my_df %>% 
  mutate(my_fuel_price_component = rep(my_file_name[file]))

my_file_list[[file]] <- my_df_to_save

}

# final data frame
my_final_fuel_df <-
  my_file_list %>% 
  ldply(.) %>%
  tbl_df
```

#### Tidy Oil Bulletin data

Remark: one can coerce time variable `my_date` that is of class character to class date by `as.Date()` function.

```
Source: local data frame [42,495 x 8]

   my_geo    my_date ExcRate Gasoline Diesel GasOilHeat FuelOil my_fuel_price_component
    (chr)      (chr)   (dbl)    (dbl)  (dbl)      (dbl)   (dbl)                   (chr)
1      AT 2016-03-14       1   387.47 409.53     373.71     191            mpc_ex_taxes
2      AT 2016-03-07       1   371.64 387.86     358.08     176            mpc_ex_taxes
3      AT 2016-02-29       1   370.81 382.03     344.54     171            mpc_ex_taxes
4      AT 2016-02-22       1   375.81 384.53     339.44     171            mpc_ex_taxes
5      AT 2016-02-15       1   369.97 372.03     331.05     171            mpc_ex_taxes
6      AT 2016-02-08       1   382.47 380.36     337.09     178            mpc_ex_taxes
7      AT 2016-02-01       1   387.47 376.19     337.01     172            mpc_ex_taxes
8      AT 2016-01-25       1   384.97 370.36     321.67     146            mpc_ex_taxes
9      AT 2016-01-18       1   392.47 385.36     329.30     165            mpc_ex_taxes
10     AT 2016-01-11       1   413.31 407.86     346.26     175            mpc_ex_taxes
..    ...        ...     ...      ...    ...        ...     ...                     ...
```

#### Session info

```
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250  LC_CTYPE=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250    LC_MONETARY=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                        LC_TIME=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tidyr_0.3.0         ggplot2_1.0.1       lubridate_1.5.0     stringr_1.0.0       readr_0.2.2        
[6] dplyr_0.4.3         plyr_1.8.3          XLConnect_0.2-11    XLConnectJars_0.2-9

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.0      digest_0.6.8     assertthat_0.1   MASS_7.3-44      grid_3.2.4       R6_2.1.1        
 [7] gtable_0.1.2     DBI_0.3.1        magrittr_1.5     scales_0.3.0     stringi_0.5-5    lazyeval_0.1.10 
[13] reshape2_1.4.1   labeling_0.3     proto_0.3-10     tools_3.2.4      munsell_0.4.2    parallel_3.2.4  
[19] colorspace_1.2-6 rJava_0.9-7
```